# Performing time consuming operation on STL container within a lock

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have an unordered_map of an unordered_map which stores a pointer of objects. The unordered map is being shared by multiple threads. I need to iterate through each object and perform some time consuming operation (like sending it through network etc) . How could I lock the multiple unordered_map so that it won't blocked for too long?

```
typedef std::unordered_map<string, classA*>MAP1;
typedef std::unordered_map<int, MAP1*>MAP2;
MAP2 map2;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexA) //how could I lock the maps? Could I reduce the lock granularity?
for(MAP2::iterator it2 = map2.begin; it2 != map2.end; it2++)
{
  for(MAP1::iterator it1 = *(it2->second).begin(); it1 != *(it2->second).end(); it1++)
  {
    //perform some time consuming operation on it1->second eg
    sendToNetwork(*(it1->second));
  }
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store all of those objects in some other structure like a List and iterate that so you don't have to lock the maps.

You can also try creating a copy of your data and work on a copy - this way your map can be modified while the copy is being worked on.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this [article by herb sutter](http://www.drdobbs.com/go-parallel/article/showArticle.jhtml;jsessionid=LJEXEUL4QMTGFQE1GHOSKH4ATMY32JVN?articleID=227500074&pgno=3) on dr dobbs that specifically addresses your question.

The general idea is to have a thread internal to an object that encapsulates the resource. The thread accepts requests to perform actions on the resource, allowing a caller to push a request and then carry on, leaving the internal thread to carry out the request.

Also you would be well advised to use [boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread.html) instead of pthread directly, it is far less painful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually it is not a good practice to hold a mutex for long periods of time. A common approach, already mentioned here, is to have an object queue which will read and process objects in a worker thread.

In your example mutexA is protecting map2 from being modified while you are iterating over it, you can do something like this:

```
std::vector<MAP1*> map1Queue;
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutexA);
for(MAP2::iterator it2 = map2.begin; it2 != map2.end; ++it2) {
  map1Queue.push_back(it2->second);
}
pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutexA);
// Now you can process objects from map1Queue in worker thread
```

The only issue is you need to guarantee that the MAP1* will still be valid, perhaps using boos::shared_ptr instead of raw_pointers.

Comment: What happen if some of map2 items erased after unlock?

Comment: You should note that in your example MAP2 and MAP1 are only related because MAP2 contains pointers to MAP1 elements, so in the above case the deletion of a MAP2 object will not cause the deletion of MAP1 elements.